# Property 'split' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that can update a `result` variable. If `result` ends up not being a string, I immediately stop the function. Otherwise, I apply a split() method to the string `result`.

The function can never crash. However, typescript claims that:

> "Property 'split' does not exist on type 'never'.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
function foo(){
let result = users[category] as { [key: string]: {} };

["employees", "tech"].forEach((k) => {
if (!result[k]) return;
return (result = result[k]);
  });

if (typeof result !== "string") return null;
// do more stuff
return result
        .split("__")
        .map((word:string) => word.toUpperCase())
        .join("")
    : result;
  }
```

How to fix this type issue?

Comment: Can you show the full code, especially where `result` gets assigned to?

Comment: When would you ever continue after the `if`? When the condition matches, you exit the function because `result` is `null`. The value of that variable never changes, so it can't be anything else than `null`.  The type of the variable is similarly just `null`. If you eliminate that case, you're left with code that cannot possibly have anything for `result`. At least according to what you've shown here.

Comment: @VLAZ The value of the variable likely changes in the `//do stuff` section of the code, a placeholder to avoid posting a wall of text/code. If it does modify it and it becomes a string, then he wants to `split` it. If it doesn't, he'll bail out. As such, `split` should not be called if `result` does not become a string in `//do stuff`, but he claims it is being called anyway, which is the reason for the question.

Comment: @JAAulde OP needs to provide a better example than us having to guess what might or might not happen in the code.

Comment: I suppose I am thinking in JS terms. TS is odd in the way it assigns. Sorry for any confusion I added.

Comment: We ***really*** need more of the code here. Your current code is not even syntactically correct - you have a `:` in the middle of the return. This seems to imply to me that you have a conditional operator which can have further impact on why TS has come to the conclusion that `result` is `never`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for providing a inefficient snippet, the code is a bit long so I wanted to go straight to the point. I have updated the snippet above. result is actually declared as an object, I've just put null to keep things simple, sorry for that. `let result = { [key: string]: {} }` result can be either this object, or a string is certain conditions are met.

Comment: "*result can be either this object, or a string*" not according to the type you've chosen for it. For TS it can only be `{ [key: string]: {} }`. You should probably better describe your types, so you 1. don't get this error 2. actually benefit from the type system.

Answer (score 3):

You are explicitly assigning a `null` value to the `result` variable:

```
let result = null;
```

The condition:

```
if (typeof result !== "string")
```

will **always** evaluate to true. The `return result...` code will be **never** executed.

If you would slightly modify your function that it would accept `result` as an argument, your condition would work as you would expect and TS would not complain.

```
function foo(result: string | null) {  // result arg can be possibly null
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the variable is simply being declared, and the `// do stuff` comment implies that something is intended to conditionally modify `result` such that it could possibly hold a string value. The OP's point is that `split` should never be called if, in fact,  `//do stuff` doesn't modify `result` to be a string, and yet it seems to get called and causes an error.

Comment: @JAAulde Perhaps you are confusing typescript with javascript. In js terms the split function will not be called indeed, however in terms of ts it should complain though to warn user that it's kind of unreachable chunk of code. Anyways - looking forward for OP clarification.

Comment: I suppose I am thinking in JS terms. TS is odd in the way it assigns. Sorry for any confusion I added.

Comment: @JAAulde It's cool, just trying to dig the case, still looking forward for OP clarification if this exactly solves his issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry for providing a inefficient snippet, the code is a bit long so I wanted to go straight to the point. I have updated the snippet above. result is actually declared as an object, I've just put null to keep things simple, sorry for that. `let result = { [key: string]: {} }` result can be either this object, or a string is certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, result is of type `null` and *only null*

If you wish to make it accept null or string, you need to explicitly declare that

```
function foo(){
let result: string | null = null
// do stuff
if (typeof result !== "string") return null;
// do more stuff
return result
        .split("__")
        .map((word:string) => word.toUpperCase())
        .join("")
    : result;
  }
```

Additionally, depending on your TS version, you can condense these checks down so it can be a little more concise (using null coalescing and optional chaining)

```
function foo(){
  let result: string | undefined;

  // do stuff to possibly make result a string
  // do more stuff

  return result
        ?.split("__")
        .map((word:string) => word.toUpperCase())
        .join("") ?? null
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the variable is simply being declared, and the `// do stuff` comment implies that something is intended to conditionally modify `result` such that it could possibly hold a string value. The OP's point is that `split` should never be called if, in fact,  `//do stuff` doesn't modify `result` to be a string, and yet it seems to get called and causes an error.

Comment: Yet ts will still complain because the `null` value is explicitly assigned.

Comment: We still need to declare the type of variable that is going to hold the data regardless of what operations happen to it after the fact

Comment: @kinduser Good point, that depends on the `strictNullCheck` option though

Comment: I suppose I am thinking in JS terms. TS is odd in the way it assigns. Sorry for any confusion I added.

Comment: Hi, sorry for providing a inefficient snippet, the code is a bit long so I wanted to go straight to the point. I have updated the snippet above. result is actually declared as an object, I've just put null to keep things simple, sorry for that. `let result = { [key: string]: {} }` result can be either this object, or a string is certain conditions are met.